# Theoretical - Given 2 Tables, is it possible to calculate the size of the resulting dataset after a join?

Tags: join, database-theory

This may not be the most appropriate exchange for this, so my apologies in advance.

I was posed this question during an interview prep session for an SQL developer role and was not given the solution to it. The question is as follows:

Given 2 tables (`Table A` and `Table B`) with the same primary key and sizes (rows) of `N` and `M` respectively, is it possible to calculate the size of the resulting table/dataset from using:

1. `Inner Join`
2. `Left Join`
3. `Full Join`

I'm really stumped on this question and as stated I was *not* given a solution. Part of me believes that there might not even be a set solution. If anyone has any pointers or solutions, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Are the PKs of A and B taken from an overlapping or disjoint sets?

Comment: @Akina your comment looks to be the solution I'm looking for. I didn't feel like creating my own table to test, so I've been using [w3's SQL editor](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all) to test. While `Full Join` isn't supported, both `Inner` and `Left` joins returned answers in line with the solution you provided. If you decide to submit your comment as an answer I'd be happy to mark as the solution; otherwise take a +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "with the same primary key" means "autoincremented started with the same value (1) without gaps", and if join expression is these PKs equiality, then the answers are:

1. `LEAST(m,n)`

Inner join will filter the record for the value which is present in both tables.

2. `n`

Left join will return all records from `tableA` independently of `tableB` content. So `tableB` content can not influence on the result.

3. `GREATEST(m,n)`

Full outer join will return the record for the value which is present in at least one table.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4944a7b496733a84705978da3ac25c34)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the cardinality of a join between A and B:

```
| A |X| B | <= |A| X |B|
```

Assume for example:

```
 A = {(k,a): (1,1),(2,1)}, B = {(k,b): (10,1),(11,1),(12,1)}
```

and the JOIN is done between A.a and B.b, the cardinality for the JOIN is 2x3=6.

If we assume that we are using the key to JOIN the tables, we know that each row in A will match at most one row in B, so the cardinality is:

```
| A |x| B | <= LEAST(|A|, |B|)
```

If we are using keys as JOIN predicate and use a LEFT JOIN, the cardinality is:

```
| A >|x| B | = |A|
```

Every row of A will be in the result set, and there is at most 1 row in B that match.

A FULL JOIN is a UNION between a LEFT and a RIGHT JOIN. If no rows match and we are using keys to JOIN:

```
| A >|x|< B | = |A >|x| B| + |B >|x| A| = |A| + |B|
```

If on the other hand there is a maximum match:

```
| A >|x|< B | = GREATEST(|A|,|B|)
```